# Flip Animation not working properly in GridView after onItemClick

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-animation, android-adapter

I have A grid view. I have A row.xml, which I am inflating in Adapter class. My row xml has two layout (One is visible and another is invisible.) I am doing flip animation. As I click on the any item of gridview then flip animation is happening, and I am doing visible the hided layout, and hiding that visible layout.
The animation is working perfectly. But the issue is that as I am clicking on any item, and scrolling other items also flipping. So as I realize that I am not getting the specific position. 
I tried the following code.

```
      @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row;

    final RecordHolder holder = new RecordHolder();

    animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.to_middle);
    animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.from_middle);

    if (convertView == null) {
        row = View.inflate(context, R.layout.row_phone_and_tablet1, null);
    } else {
        //row = View.inflate(context, R.layout.row_phone_and_tablet1, null);
        row = convertView;
    }

    holder.frontImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.myimage_imgvw);
    holder.frontMobileName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name_txtvw);
    holder.frontPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.price_txtvw);
    holder.backMobileName = (TextView) row
            .findViewById(R.id.tv_device_name);
    holder.descOne = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc_first);
    holder.descTwo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc_second);
    holder.descThree = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc_third);
    holder.descFour = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc_fourth);
    holder.ccEmi = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_price_ccemi);
    holder.financeEmi = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_price_finance);
    holder.frontlayout = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.frontlayout);
    holder.backlayout = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.backlayout);
    holder.viewdetails = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.viewdetails);
    holder.tv_front_inr = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_front_inr);
    holder.tv_description = (TextView) row
            .findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
    holder.tv_price_ccemi_inr = (TextView) row
            .findViewById(R.id.tv_price_ccemi_inr);
    holder.tv_ccemi_price = (TextView) row
            .findViewById(R.id.tv_ccemi_price);
    holder.tv_price_finance_inr = (TextView) row
            .findViewById(R.id.tv_price_finance_inr);
    holder.tv_financeemi_price = (TextView) row
            .findViewById(R.id.tv_financeemi_price);
    holder.parentLayout = (LinearLayout) row
            .findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);




    final PhoneAndTabletItem phoneAndTableItem = data.get(position);
    holder.viewdetails.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, ViewPhoneInformation.class);
            i.putExtra("SKU_CODE", phoneAndTableItem.getSku_code());
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // row.setTag(holder);



    holder.frontMobileName.setText(phoneAndTableItem.getModel_name());
    holder.frontPrice.setText(phoneAndTableItem.getCc_emi());
    holder.backMobileName.setText(phoneAndTableItem.getModel_name());
    holder.descOne.setText(phoneAndTableItem.getKey_feat_1());
    holder.descTwo.setText(phoneAndTableItem.getKey_feat_2());
    holder.descThree.setText(phoneAndTableItem.getKey_feat_3());
    holder.descFour.setText(phoneAndTableItem.getKey_feat_4());
    holder.ccEmi.setText(phoneAndTableItem.getCc_emi());
    holder.financeEmi.setText(phoneAndTableItem.getFinance_emi());

    holder.frontMobileName.setTypeface(tvHalvetica);
    holder.frontPrice.setTypeface(tvHalvetica);
    holder.backMobileName.setTypeface(tvHalvetica);
    holder.descOne.setTypeface(tvHalvetica);
    holder.descTwo.setTypeface(tvHalvetica);
    holder.descThree.setTypeface(tvHalvetica);
    holder.descFour.setTypeface(tvHalvetica);
    holder.ccEmi.setTypeface(tvHalvetica);
    holder.financeEmi.setTypeface(tvHalvetica);
    holder.tv_front_inr.setTypeface(tvHalvetica);
    holder.tv_description.setTypeface(tvHalvetica);
    holder.tv_price_ccemi_inr.setTypeface(tvHalvetica);
    holder.tv_ccemi_price.setTypeface(tvHalvetica);
    holder.tv_price_finance_inr.setTypeface(tvHalvetica);
    holder.tv_financeemi_price.setTypeface(tvHalvetica);

    // here we are rotating the LinearLayout...
    holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setTag(position);
            // Start Array Check...
            Toast.makeText(context, "onClick id: " + v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (selected_views.contains((Integer) v.getTag())) {

                holder.frontlayout.clearAnimation();
                holder.frontlayout.setAnimation(animation1);
                holder.frontlayout.startAnimation(animation1);

                HashSet hs = new HashSet();
                hs.addAll(selected_views);
                selected_views.clear();
                selected_views.addAll(hs);
                selected_views.remove((Integer) v.getTag());
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                isBackOfCardShowing = true;
            } else {
                if (selected_views.size() == 0) {
                    holder.frontlayout.clearAnimation();
                    holder.frontlayout.setAnimation(animation1);
                    holder.frontlayout.startAnimation(animation1);
                    selected_views.add((Integer) v.getTag());
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    array_size = selected_views.size();
                    isBackOfCardShowing = false;
                }
                else {
                    holder.frontlayout.clearAnimation();
                    holder.frontlayout.setAnimation(animation1);
                    holder.frontlayout.startAnimation(animation1);
                    selected_views.add((Integer) v.getTag());
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    isBackOfCardShowing = false;
                }
            }
            // End Array Check...

            animation1.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                        if (isBackOfCardShowing) {
                            holder.frontlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.backlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // holder.frontImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.accesories_dashboard);
                        } else {
                            holder.backlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.frontlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // holder.frontImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.vas_dashboard);
                        }
                        holder.frontlayout.clearAnimation();
                        holder.frontlayout.setAnimation(animation2);
                        holder.frontlayout.startAnimation(animation2);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    holder.parentLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            String inserted="";
            final String SKV_CODE = phoneAndTableItem.getSku_code().toString();
            handler.open();
                inserted = handler.insertData(phoneAndTableItem.getModel_name(),    
                                              phoneAndTableItem.getKey_feat_1(),
                                              phoneAndTableItem.getKey_feat_2(),
                                              phoneAndTableItem.getKey_feat_3(),    
                                              phoneAndTableItem.getKey_feat_4(),
                                              phoneAndTableItem.getCc_emi(),        
                                              phoneAndTableItem.getFinance_emi(),
                                              SKV_CODE);
                handler.close();

                if (inserted.equals("inserted")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, " Added to Shortlist " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if(inserted.equals("error")){
                    Toast.makeText(context, " Already present in Shortlist " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, " Try again " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            return true;
        }
    });

    return row;
}
static class RecordHolder {
    ImageView frontImage;
    TextView frontMobileName;
    TextView frontPrice;
    TextView backMobileName;
    TextView descOne;
    TextView descTwo;
    TextView descThree;
    TextView descFour;
    TextView ccEmi;
    TextView financeEmi;
    LinearLayout frontlayout, backlayout, parentLayout;
    Button viewdetails;
    TextView tv_front_inr, tv_description, tv_price_ccemi_inr,
            tv_ccemi_price, tv_price_finance_inr, tv_financeemi_price;

}
```

This code is showing properly position, but below when I am scrolling, then still I am getting flipped other items also. Please help me.

Comment: can you post your adapter code?

Comment: now check I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact position of item clicked in a GridView, you need to use setOnItemClickListener on your GridView reference, example:

```
       GridView g = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

       g.setAdapter(new ImageAdopterShow(this)); // your custom adaptor object goes here


       g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "position of item is " +position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
```

This is the way i get the position of any item in my GridView. Hope this answers your question.

Your Question is kind of misleading If you can get the item position then you need to change your question for animations not working in GridView properly.

Comment: I am applying the animation of specific item of grid view, but it reflects animation on other items of gridview simultaneously.

Comment: I can't use onItemClickListener(). I need to use the layoutClickListener() in adapter class. My requirement is little bit different.

Comment: Can you post the code of your entire class ? Where is `holder`, `backlayout` and `frontlayout`

Comment: Without Understanding the relevant code, I'm afraid I won't be able to help you bro.

Comment: I posted the all getView().

Comment: You are applying the `LinearLayout` on each item in the `GridView`?? The `LinearLayout` which you are rotating ? If thats the case then its obvious why rest of the items are also rotating

Comment: I also confused, that why other elements are rotating. Actually I think issue is because of View v.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68274/discussion-between-sharp-edge-and-amit-jayaswal).

Comment: Actually Linear Layout is my parent layout